# Button is showing on screen but textField is not appearing every time. what is the error in my code?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am setting textfied and a button programmatically. The button is showing when we run the code but not textfield. is there any problem with constraints or any other please help.

```
let submitButton: UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton(type:.system)
    btn.backgroundColor = .blue
    btn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    btn.tintColor = .white
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn.clipsToBounds = true
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
let textBox: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = "we are learning iOs"
    textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(textBox)
    setupTexBoxLayout()
   view.addSubview(submitButton)
   setupSubmitBUttonLayout()

}
private func setupTexBoxLayout(){
    textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    textBox.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}

private func setupSubmitBUttonLayout(){
    submitButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textBox.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    submitButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
}

}
```

Comment: Where is `textBox` supposed to appear at what size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and debug it.

You have not specified height for textview so it is not showing it.

You can check the below code. I have added height constraint to it and it is displaying your textfield.

If you do not specify a height for textfield then it will take 0 height by default.

```
    private func setupTexBoxLayout(){
    textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    textBox.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    textBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
}
```